# PYO, How are route audio to sound card device

Tags: python, audio

I am using pyo to play some audio on my code. The set up is as follow:

```
from pyo import *
import time
s = Server(sr=44100, nchnls=2, buffersize=1024, duplex=0).boot()
s.start()
```

This will results in audio being played on the default device (internal speaker). However, when I connected the external soundcard. The audio still plays from the internal speakers. So I wonder how to set it up.

I checkex the API, it said to use setInOutDevice(x) : Set both input and output devices. See pa_list_devices(). But I dont know how to use pa_list_devices() to output the list of audio devices.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

From the python interpreter:

```
>>> pa_list_devices()
```

will print a list of devices. Find the number for the device you want, and use the setInOutDevice(number) BEFORE booting the server, like this:

```
s = Server()
s.setInOutDevice(number)
s.boot()
```